# What are the prerequisites for enrolling in an undergraduate Classical Differential Geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I would like to know what are the prerequisite knowledge a student must have in order to completely understand everything covered in an undergraduate Classical Differential Geometry course.
Thank you.

EDIT: I have previously enrolled in a General Relativity (for physicists) course, a Linear Algebra(for mathematicians) course, a single-variable course and a multivariable calculus course(both for physicists). The course that I want to enroll in is a course taught to mathematicians so it is more rigorous than the mathematics courses that I have been taught.

Comment: I took differential geometry as an undergrad using this text: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf.  From my experience, I'd say one should have a strong background in linear algebra and single variable and vector calculus.  Real analysis couldn't hurt either.  Some differential geometry courses use differential forms, which are covered in some multivariable analysis texts like Dr. Shifrin's, Hubbard & Hubbard, etc.  Differential forms aren't 100% necessary to get a good intro, but they will vastly simplify a lot of things like the Gauss' and Codazzi equations.

Comment: What text is the course you want to attend using? For an undergraduate "classical differential geometry" course, your background should be more or less sufficient. For an introductory course to manifolds and tangent bundles, you will need multivariable analysis (inverse and implicit function theorems) and some point-set topology. This, however, is ordinarily a graduate-level course.

Comment: @TedShifrin The professor will be mostly using Do Carmo's Differential geometry of curves and surfaces

Comment: That is a common choice. I personally find it a bit overly sophisticated for most audiences, as the style of the book makes it difficult if students haven't had some more rigorous exposure to multivariable calculus/analysis and some point-set topology. For example, doCarmo says he expects students to know the implicit function theorem. If you don't have time to take these courses, you might try my YouTube lectures (picking appropriately) and it might help, also, to look at my differential geometry notes (both linked in my profile) to which Kaj referred. These will help you get going.

Comment: @TedShifrin I will most surely check them out and maybe start studying Differential Geometry near Christmas! Thanks a lot.